# Join two records into single record in xslt

Tags: xslt-2.0

## Request

```
<Records>
        <Record>
            <ACCOUNT>460029</ACCOUNT>
            <ENTITY>1851</ENTITY>
            <UD1>FY17</UD1>
            <UD2>457001</UD2>
            <UD3>116029</UD3>
            <UD4>0</UD4>
            <UD5>458004</UD5>
            <UD6>Dec</UD6>
            <UD7>DeferredIncome</UD7>
            <AMOUNT>0</AMOUNT>
        </Record>
        <Record>
            <ACCOUNT>460029</ACCOUNT>
            <ENTITY>1851</ENTITY>
            <UD1>FY17</UD1>
            <UD2>457001</UD2>
            <UD3>116029</UD3>
            <UD4>0</UD4>
            <UD5>458004</UD5>
            <UD6>Dec</UD6>
            <UD7>OutsBalance</UD7>
            <AMOUNT>3400</AMOUNT>
        </Record>
        <Record>
            <ACCOUNT>460029</ACCOUNT>
            <ENTITY>1851</ENTITY>
            <UD1>FY17</UD1>
            <UD2>457002</UD2>
            <UD3>116029</UD3>
            <UD4>0</UD4>
            <UD5>458008</UD5>
            <UD6>Jan</UD6>
            <UD7>DeferredIncome</UD7>
            <AMOUNT>20</AMOUNT>
        </Record>
        <Record>
            <ACCOUNT>460029</ACCOUNT>
            <ENTITY>1851</ENTITY>
            <UD1>FY17</UD1>
            <UD2>457002</UD2>
            <UD3>116029</UD3>
            <UD4>0</UD4>
            <UD5>458008</UD5>
            <UD6>Jan</UD6>
            <UD7>OtsBalance</UD7>
            <AMOUNT>0</AMOUNT>
        </Record>
    </Records>
```

## response

```
  <Records>
            <Record>
                <ACCOUNT>460029</ACCOUNT>
                <ENTITY>1851</ENTITY>
                <UD1>FY17</UD1>
                <UD2>457001</UD2>
                <UD3>116029</UD3>
                <UD4>0</UD4>
                <UD5>458004</UD5>
                <UD6>Dec</UD6>
                <DeferredIncome>0</DeferredIncome>
                <OutsBalance>3400</OutsBalance>
            </Record>
            <Record>
                <ACCOUNT>460029</ACCOUNT>
                <ENTITY>1851</ENTITY>
                <UD1>FY17</UD1>
                <UD2>457002</UD2>
                <UD3>116029</UD3>
                <UD4>0</UD4>
                <UD5>458008</UD5>
                <UD6>Jan</UD6>
                <DeferredIncome>20</DeferredIncome>
                <OutsBalance>0</OutsBalance>
            </Record>
        </Records>
<br/>
```

I have a requirement where i need to merge two records into one records in xslt.
There will be more than 1000 records so running for-each inside for-each will increase number of iteration.
Is there any better way of doing it?Any help is appreciated.Basically each unique record(from Amount to UD7) will have two records deffredAmount and outsBalance. Need to club these two records with defferedAmount and outsBalance

Comment: Can you show us some minimal but complete XML code samples of input and wanted output together with an explanation of the values you want to use to join your data? You can certainly group two sequences with e.g. `xsl:for-each-group select="foo, bar" group-by="account"` in XSLT 2.

Comment: @MartinHonnen i have added reqq and resp xml as per your req

Comment: I am not sure I understand from those two samples which data you want to use to merge or join `Record` elements, are this several child elements ("from Amount to UD7" seems to suggest that)? Are in a position to use XSLT 3 (e.g. with Saxon 9.8) instead of XSLT 2 as XSLT 3 allows `composite="yes"` on `for-each-group group-by="ACCOUNT, ENTITY, UD1, UD2"` and that would make it easier to solve that grouping?

Answer (score 0):

As I already suggested in a comment, this seems to be like a text book case to use the new XSLT 3 feature `for-each-group group-by composite="yes"`, i.e. to use a sequence of items you want to use as the grouping keys for the `group-by` expression and to indicate with `composite="yes"` that all of them form the composite key to group items.

So for your example with the XSLT 3 code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Records">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="Record" group-by="*[position() le 8]" composite="yes">
              <xsl:copy>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="* except (UD7, AMOUNT)"/>
                  <DeferredIncome>{ sum(current-group()[UD7 = 'DeferredIncome']/AMOUNT) }</DeferredIncome>
                  <OutsBalance>{ sum(current-group()[UD7 = ('OtsBalance', 'OutsBalance')]/AMOUNT) }</OutsBalance>
              </xsl:copy>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtqC outputs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Records>
   <Record>
      <ACCOUNT>460029</ACCOUNT>
      <ENTITY>1851</ENTITY>
      <UD1>FY17</UD1>
      <UD2>457001</UD2>
      <UD3>116029</UD3>
      <UD4>0</UD4>
      <UD5>458004</UD5>
      <UD6>Dec</UD6>
      <DeferredIncome>0</DeferredIncome>
      <OutsBalance>3400</OutsBalance>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <ACCOUNT>460029</ACCOUNT>
      <ENTITY>1851</ENTITY>
      <UD1>FY17</UD1>
      <UD2>457002</UD2>
      <UD3>116029</UD3>
      <UD4>0</UD4>
      <UD5>458008</UD5>
      <UD6>Jan</UD6>
      <DeferredIncome>20</DeferredIncome>
      <OutsBalance>0</OutsBalance>
   </Record>
</Records>
```

I am not sure whether the check `UD7 = ('OtsBalance', 'OutsBalance')` was necessary due to typos in your sample data or whether your real data needs that because it contains different spellings of that element value.